# Get text from dynamically-filled textarea

Tags: javascript, event-handling

The issue seems to be simple, but I really don't understand. Why the alert window is blank after I type something in the textarea and press the button?

```js
const source = document.querySelector('textarea#source').textContent;
  
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(source);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="source" rows="25"></textarea>
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: querySelector doesn't return live DOM, just a ref/snapshot of dom at that moment.

Comment: @bogdanoff Thanks! I have forgot about this. But changing the first line to `document.getElementById('source').textContent;` doesn't solve the problem. So it seems there is something more about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change two things. First, the property you need is `value` not `textContent`.

But we don't just replace it because
by declaring

```
const source = document.querySelector('textarea#source').value;
```

we're setting `source` to a string *by value* not *by reference*. Which means that we're taking what the value is at that moment and set it.So instead, we just set `source` to reference the element object itself, since setting variables to objects is done by reference.

```
const source = document.querySelector('textarea#source') // The textArea element
```

Then when event triggers, our handler calls `source.value`:

```js
const source = document.querySelector('textarea#source'); // The textArea element
  
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(source.value);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="source" rows="25"></textarea>
<button>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`const source = document.querySelector('textarea#source').textContent`

Above line won't mutate when DOM content changes, because its no longer an object. Its just a string (only object like datatypes can mutate) so, do this intead.

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('#source') //document.getElementById('source')

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(inp.textContent)
});
```

```html
<div id="source" contenteditable>
  hello
</div>
<hr/>
<button>check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the value of source is defined when that block of code is loaded while the alert is triggered onclick, try this approach and see if it works

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const source = document.querySelector('textarea#source').textContent;
  alert(source);
});
```